# Flexbox with direction: column but multi-column stack by-side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Current layout:
[image: Current layout]

Hi, i made a layout with `flexbox` and it was set `flex-direction: row;` then it arranged (1.left) (2.right) (3.left)(4.right), which i set the child to be `width: 50%`.

But what i need to archive is more to `flex-direction: column`, but to have 2 column which the bottom half of the items will move to the right.

Desired result:
[image: Desired result]

Current code :

```
    .ds-content div{
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: flex-start;
     }
```

Change to direction: column;

```
    .ds-content div{
         display: inline-flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         align-items: flex-start;
         flex-direction: column;
         width: 100%;
         height: 150px;
     }
```

The issue i have is i cannot set a fix height for this flexbox (to push bottom-half content to the right), the content is dynamic fetch from user admin; dynamic in terms of content length and amount of child.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: show the HTML please

Comment: If you cannot set a fixed height for the container, then how is the column supposed to know where to wrap?

Comment: @jen Wong, I know its very old question, do you have answer for this one?

Answer (score 2):

check my 
[solution in Codepen](http://codepen.io/TibicenasDesign/pen/KzbZNO)

I keep the `flex-direction: row` in order to use `align-content: stretch`  and have equal height in the flex-items.
Now you just have to play with the `order` property.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! :) Ya, i thought of using order, but the problem the length of the set is different, it can have 4 items, 5 items, or 10 items (it was fetch from cms) , so i can't think of a logic on how to set the order.

Comment: oh ok, you didn't say that on the title, just 4. 

Can you use javascript ? or this have to be implemented only in CSS/SASS/Less

Answer (score 2):

I think for this it's better to use columns:

```
.ds-content div {
     width: 100%;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

browser support might be an issue, though...

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a solution to this for a long time, I found the solution.

If you use an Angular you can do it simply that way:

```
  .ds-content div{
         display: inline-flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         align-items: flex-start;
         flex-direction: column;
         width: 50%;
     }
```

```
<div class="ds-content">
  <div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of anArray| slice:0:(anArray.length/2+anArray.length%2)">
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of anArray| slice:(anArray.length/2+anArray.length%2):anArray.length">
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

for only HTML CSS JS, you can use:

```js
     const anArray = [
            { tittle: "1", body: "Example 1" },
            { tittle: "2", body: "Example 2" },
            { tittle: "3", body: "Example 3" },
            { tittle: "4", body: "Example 4" },
            { tittle: "5", body: "Example 5" },
            { tittle: "6", body: "Example 6" }
        ]
        
        function fill2flexColumn() {
            let value = '';
            let part1 = anArray.slice(0 , anArray.length/2+anArray.length%2);
            let part2 = anArray.slice(anArray.length/2+anArray.length%2,anArray.length );

             part1.forEach((post) => {
                value += `<li>${post.tittle} - ${post.body}</li>`;
            });
            document.querySelector('.ds-content .part1').innerHTML = value;
            value ='';
            part2.forEach((post) => {
                value += `<li>${post.tittle} - ${post.body}</li>`;
            });

            document.querySelector('.ds-content .part2').innerHTML = value;
        };
        
        fill2flexColumn();
```

```css
.ds-content{
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ds-content div{
         display: inline-flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         align-items: flex-start;
         flex-direction: column;
         width: 50%;
     }
```

```html
    <body>
       <div class="ds-content">
        <div class="part1"></div>
        <div class="part2"></div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing flex-direction column with flex-wrap and expand beyond the height you get this behavior automatically.

```
element.style {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 470px;
}
```

`